# How to send sec-websocket-accept key for Socket.io websocket in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I try to setup an Socket IO connection between Client and Server in NodeJs. The connection is working with "Transports: Polling"  but not for "Transports: Websocket".

Client side:

```
var socket =io.connect('/',{secure: true, transports:['polling','websocket']});
```

In Chrome I see there is an issue with the Sec WebSocket Accept key handshake

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.myurl.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=5NXT5eSPYCTSBlXqAACv' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value
```

Below the server side code that creates the HTTP reponse:

1. get the sec-websocket-key
2. add 258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11
3. create hash/base64 with crypto module
4. populare http accept handshake header value
5. (try to) reply to client with header...

but for some reason it did not reach the client side with the Socket.emit function (no response visible in chome dev tool).  Any suggestion how to repond to handshake request with socket.io ?

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var crypto = require ('crypto');

//App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('listen to request on port 3000')
});

//Socket setup
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection',function(socket){                                //begin connection
    console.log('made socket connection',socket.id);
    var key = JSON.stringify(socket.handshake.headers);
    var keystring = key.toString().split(',')[18].split(':')[1].replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1'); 
    var accept = keystring + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    var acceptSha = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(accept);
    var acceptB64 = acceptSha.digest('base64');
    var header = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" +
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" +
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
        "WebSocket-Origin: https://www.myurl.com\r\n" +
        "WebSocket-Location: wss://www.myurl.com\r\n" +
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:" + acceptB64 + "\r\n\r\n";
    socket.emit(header);
    })    //end connection
```